# How will I be able to tell/validate the form depending on the value?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#second_ins").hide("fast");
$("#third_ins").hide("fast");

$('#number').change(function() {

  if($("#number").val() == "2") {
      $("#second_ins").show("fast");


  }else if ($("#number").val() > "2") {
      $("#second_ins").show("fast");
      $("#third_ins").show("fast");
}else {
      $("#second_ins").hide("fast");
      $("#third_ins").hide("fast");
}
});
```

I have this code, basically what it is doing is to show/hide a  depending on the value in the input id="number".

Now, I would like to seek help on how will I be able make a validation on this that if it is hidden then it won't require a value.

What I mean is that for example: input id="number(value is 1) so basically, the hidden div/s second and third ins should not cause the form not to submit. because they're required values (validations)

Is there a way to check like this?
input_name : {
    required : "#cat_cas_same_address:unchecked"
}

But we'll check if the value of #number not if it is unchecked or checked.

Comment: you say if it is hidden then it wont require a value.. what is 'it' here? You mean #number?

Comment: What I mean is that for example:
 <input id="number>(value is 1)</input>
so basically, the hidden <div/>s second and third ins should not cause the form not to submit. because they're required values (validations)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation on [jQuery for `Hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), I would suggest you can do a check to determine if the style attribute `display:none;` is present:

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except
>   that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache
>   so that display can later be restored to its initial value.

So, for any desired element that is hidden using `Hide`, the following might suffice...

```
var isVisible = $("#hiddenthing").css("display") == "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$('#id').is(":hidden")` to check the element is hidden or not

if element is hidden then it will return true if not false

Answer (score 0):

You can check object property "display" if its not "block" but "none" (hidden)
eg:

```
   if (!$(object).css("display") == 'none')
   //do something
```